# Show/hide content on the WP7 pushpin

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a puspin ContentTemplate:

```
<my:Pushpin.ContentTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1}"/>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text2}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</my:Pushpin.ContentTemplate>
```

How could I show and hide it clickking on the pushpin (Could be a lot of pushpins on the map and I need to show the content of the clicked one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already binding text to your Pushpin. You can bind visibility to it as well. I am assuming here that each `Pushpin` is binding to a seperate object.

```
<my:Pushpin.ContentTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text2}"/>
     </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</my:Pushpin.ContentTemplate>
```

If you don't know how to use converters, then you can search for them and find all kinds of answers that should be helpful. I'll include one [here](http://thejoyofcode.com/Five_minute_recipe_for_a_decent_BoolToVisibilityConverter.aspx) for convenience

Comment: Because I have to hide the content of the all pushpins every time. Is that OK?

Comment: You can start with all of the content hidden. Then whenever the pushpin is selected, change its `IsSelected` property to true as well as make it your 'Current Pushpin`. Whenever a different pushpin is clicked, you turn off the old one and turn on the new one. So, you don't have to hide all of them everytime... just once and then one every time.